# How to draw a resource layout on a canvas?

Tags: java, android, canvas

How do I convert my layout file into a bitmap image?
I can take a screenshot of the current view but is there any way I can capture my layout file without changing the current view.

Comment: Hi Shashank, Welcome to SO . Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30196965/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-current-activity-and-then-share-it and try it.

Comment: I tried this but it only work for the current layout but I want to a screenshot of another layout.

Comment: without changing the current view?? NO .. because it haven't drawn yet ..

Comment: @ADM then how about if I draw it temporarily on current activity and then change it back?

Comment: @ShasankShahi See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53181261/custom-view-component-is-not-showing-up-on-the-screenshot/53197087#53197087) for the basic approach. You do not have to change anything onscreen.